# How to select * from a database where a column != a value in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now I'm doing the following query to display all the tasks in a simple project management app I'm working on.

```
Task.find(:all, :order => 'updated_at DESC')
```

This is fine and works great although I have a private column that is set to 1 if the task is private. How do I select all the tasks in the database where private doesn't == 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [ARel](https://github.com/rails/arel) should do the trick:

```
Task.where(:private => false).order("updated_at DESC")
```

Edit:  That's assuming your column is either 1 or 0.  If not, you can use the lt/gt comparisons, which will look something like this:

```
Task.where(Task.arel_table[:private].gt(1)).order("updated_at DESC")
```

Comment: Just note: this is a Rails 3-specific solution. If the questioner is using Rails 2 they'll need something else :)

Comment: And if dropping down to arel_table is a bit much for you, you can just do `Task.where("tasks.private > 1").order(...)`

Answer (score 1):

muffinista's solution is the best if you're using Rails 3. if you're still on Rails 2, you'll need to use conditions:

```
Task.find(:all, :conditions => {:private => false}, :order => 'updated_at DESC')
```

or

```
Task.find(:all, :conditions => "private != 1", :order => 'updated_at DESC')
```